# MySQL convert time to HH:MM

Tags: mysql, datetime, time

Why does `SELECT STR_TO_DATE('07:30 PM','%H:%I %p');` return `NULL`?

I'd expect to see `19:30`

More Context:

I'm trying to query a table where the time column values are stored as `HH:MM PM`. Example:

`SELECT * FROM table where (STR_TO_DATE(table.time, '%H:%I %p') < NOW())`

Comment: It might be a typo, because it just seems weird, but the official docs state `%I` is for hour and `%i` is for minutes. (Alternatively, it looks like you can just use `%r` for the whole string.) [DATE_FORMAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)

Comment: @Uueerdo `%H` is for military time, 00-23, `%h` or `%I` is for standard time, 00-12, with AM/PM given by `%p`.

Comment: @JoeStefanelli Yeah, `%H` is likely to cause them problems as well; I don't see how `23:00 AM` could be handled gracefully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've mangled some format codes. It should be `'07:30 PM','%h:%i %p'`.
Additionally, you need a SQL mode that allows invalid dates because of [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date):

> Unspecified date or time parts have a value of 0, so incompletely specified values in str produce a result with some or all parts set to 0

```
mysql> SET @@SESSION.sql_mode='TRADITIONAL';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT
    -> STR_TO_DATE('07:30 PM','%H:%I %p') as original,
    -> STR_TO_DATE('07:30 PM','%h:%i %p') as fixed;
+----------+-------+
| original | fixed |
+----------+-------+
| NULL     | NULL  |
+----------+-------+
1 row in set, 3 warnings (0.00 sec)

mysql> SET @@SESSION.sql_mode='';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT
    -> STR_TO_DATE('07:30 PM','%H:%I %p') as original,
    -> STR_TO_DATE('07:30 PM','%h:%i %p') as fixed;
+----------+----------+
| original | fixed    |
+----------+----------+
| NULL     | 19:30:00 |
+----------+----------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 1):

`NOW()` returns a datetime, something like `2014-11-22 12:45:34`. You probably want to be comparing times, not dates as you aren't comparing the actual day, just the time. Try using `CURTIME()` instead. Additionally, `%I` is for hours, you want `%i`for minutes. And `%H` is for a 12 hour format, you want `%h` for a 24 hour format. So your statement should be more like:

```
SELECT * FROM table where (STR_TO_DATE(table.time, '%h:%i %p') < CURTIME())
```

For future reference, here's a table of format codes from the MySql docs:
[image]

See the original documentation here:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html